# signal handlers not terminating the parent but enters on an endless loop

Tags: c, signals, handler

Maybe this question was asked by someone else, but the questions that I've been able to check does not contain the answers i need. I'm also a newbie in c programming language.
I'm writing a program that executes a string array passed into it (string commands). If the program comes across `exit` word in the string, then the whole program, should terminate.
I'm using a loop to process these words, and a child process to prevent termination of the program without user authorisation (like how CMD works).
Now the problem is terminating both the parent and the child at the same time.

1. I cannot use `exit` or `_exit` because they will terminate only the child process and not the parent.
2. After waiting for the child to terminate, i cannot use the condition `WIFEXIT` because there are other minor conditions that are intended to terminate the child only.
   So, i tried to use signals to terminate the program. I have two signal handlers functions, for the child and parent.

```
void sig_handler_child(int __attribute__ ((unused)) signum)
{
        puts("dead child\n");  /* for testing the program*/
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
}
```

```
void sig_handler_parent(int __attribute__ ((unused)) signum)
{
        int ext_val;

        puts("killing parent\n");  /*for test purposes*/
        ext_val = atoi(getenv("EXIT_VAL"));
        exit(ext_val);
}
```

I can't post the whole program here since it's very "long". But this is how I've set my program

```
#include {...}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]) {
    /*some conditions*/
   myfunc(env);
   return (0);
}

void myfunc(char *env[]) {
   pid_t session;
   (...)

   while (true) {
     /*get user inputs and instructions*/
     session = fork();
     if (session == -1) {
       perror("fork");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
    if (session == 0) {
      signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler_child);
      /*condition and another function- myfunc2- is called here*/
    }
    waitpid(session, &wstatus, 0); /*wait before repeating the loop*/
  }
  signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler_parent);
}

void myfunc2(char *argv[]) {
   char *exitc = "exit";
   if (strcmp(argv[0], exitc) == 0)
     {
       if (argv[1] != NULL
          setenv("EXIT_VAL", argv[1], 1);
       else
          setenv("EXIT_VAL", "0", 1);
       kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    }
}
```

now when i pass the exit command, instead of the program terminatting, It enters in an endless loop on the sig handlers (printing text on sig_handler_child)

```
dead child

dead child

zsh: user-defined signal 1  ./hsh
                                                                                
dead child

dead child

dead child
/*(And it goes on forever and rejecting ctrl + c, ctrl + \)*/
```

On my previous first tests on the program, the results were

```
dead child

killing parent

zsh: user-defined signal 1  ./hsh
                                                                                
dead child

dead child

dead child
/*(and it goes on forever and rejecting ctrl + \, ctrl + x). It stops after 10+ cancel attemps*/
```

I'm tired of this and i hope you guys will help me out.

Comment: Presumably, the `{` after `signal()` should be `}`, should it not?

Comment: The child could exit with a status that indicates to the parent that it should exit too.  Then you can use `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, which status is that?? I've dine my research - although there is no enough research - and i didn't get that. I don't want to exit the parent with exit from the child because there are other exit conditions on the child that do not request for parent to exit too

Comment: When the child calls `exit()`, the argument value (modulo 256) is available to the parent via `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  Your child can exit with different values to indicate different conditions.

Comment: ooh!, I didn't think of that. Thanks, let me see what i can do. Thanks again for the tip